# Blink-engine SVG rendering Bug in feGaussianBlur filter by stdDeviation small value (under 0.8). Seeking Workaround

Tags: html, svg, svg-filters

All browsers (Chrome, Opera, MS Edge, ...) based on [**Blink-engine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)) have SVG rendering bug in [**`feGaussianBlur`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feGaussianBlur) filter by `stdDeviation` small values – less then `0.8`

The blurring effect works in this browsers based on Blink-engine only if we set the attribute `stdDeviation` to "`0.8`" and higher.

On the following picture you could see how looks the blurring effect rendering in different browsers by `stdDeviation` different values:

[image: Blink-engine SVG rendering Bug in feGaussianBlur filter by stdDeviation small value (under 0.8)]

I have the following code:

```html
<svg width="18" height="18" style="margin:9px">
<defs>
    <filter id="blurMe">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=".3" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
    <symbol id="BlinkBug" viewBox="0 0 18 18" filter="url(#blurMe)">
        <path d="M9,3H10L14,7V8L8,14H7L3,10V9z" fill="#0af" stroke="#14c"/>
        <path d="M1,1L16,16M1,16L16,1" fill="none" stroke="#14c"/>
    </symbol>
</defs>
<use href="#BlinkBug"/>
</svg>
```

You could also find the same code on my [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/bharata/pen/zYBjJBz).

When I change the attribute `stdDeviation` to "`0.8`" then the blurring effect is to big for my small icon and lines in the center of my icon are unrecognizable (see picture above).

What I have tried: I had added the following filter to my filter:

```html
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                     0 1 0 0 0 
                                     0 0 1 0 0 
                                     0 0 0 1.5 0"/>
```

But it works only if the `feGaussianBlur` filter works.

I had also tried to use `stroke-width="1.5"` but it does not help without blurring effect.

I can not also change this SVG icon `width` and `height` attributes from `18` to `54` to have on this way the blurring effect because I need it in original size.

How can I replace this filter? Maybe we have another similar filter with matrix or combination of filters or something like this?

I would like to find a workaround.

*I will also try to report this bug to Blink developers.*

Comment: use a bigger viewBox and generally make everything bigger except for the stdDeviation. Note that Firefox filters don't work below 0.27 so all browsers have issues with small enough numbers.

Comment: Surely not a coincidence that 0.27 + 0.5 ≈ 0.8 so Chrome is rounding slightly differently to Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson, thanks! I have tried to add `width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 21 21"` to the `symbol` element, but in Blink browsers it does not add the blurring effect. This makes the element smaller. Or how do you mean it?

Comment: Actually that doesn't work. Chrome must perform the viewBox scaling before it does the filtering.

Comment: @RobertLongson, yes, unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work in all browsers! I have tried to scale the icon 10 times biggger and then also to scale it 2 times smaller without blurring effect  in all browsers.